# What is the first up date and what exactly first algorithm of Renaissance?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

Charlie Munger mentioned in Acquired Podcast

*Renaissance, the first algorithm was so simple. They sifted all this data for the past and what did they decide? Up, up, which were two closing prices, and down, down were more common than down, up, or up, down.
Once they realized that's the way it was for various reasons deeper than the psychology of man, man is a natural trend follower, he's been gambling short-term, and they just program the computers to automatically buy on one thing on the first up day and sell before the end of the second day.*

What does the first up day here mean? Say day 1 the stock close at $90, day 2 the stock closed at 100, and we can consider day 3 is the first up day?  And what exactly first algorithm of Renaissance?

Comment: [This book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/073521798X) may be a better source.